# Can't find ARP tab after pressing N

Tags: rigging

noob question, but couldn't find it after googling either.
I just can't find ARP tab. In fact most of them. Only "Item, Wiew and Tool" tabs come up after pressing N.
I need ARP tab to set up the Auto Rig Pro plugin.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Auto Rig Pro version 3.41 or above? Have you installed the add-on?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Turns out, I had the add-on installed, but I didn't check the dot on it, to activate it. All my addons were gray and unchecked and I thought, this is how they are and didn't pay attention to that.